# Non Parametric Test Equivalent to an ANOVA

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, nonparametric

I am looking to do a non-parametric test of a 2x2 mixed anova as my dependent variables are far from normally distributed?

Comment: Note: ANOVA assumption number 2: Normality – the distributions of the **residuals** are normal.

Comment: The nonparametric equivalent of ANOVA is Kruskal–Wallis one-way analysis of variance.

Comment: Define the experimental design, i.e., what 2x2 and mixed mean in your context.

Comment: My 2 factors are participant gender (between) and then the gender portrayed in the vignettes I use - but all participants see both conditions so this is my within variable.

Comment: So you have a 2 x 2 table of counts???

Comment: Yeah! I have a 2x2 table of counts

Comment: So, ANOVA is irrelevant. See a text on categorical data analysis.